# Problems with image hover zoom transition

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

I'm using this image zoom transition when i hover over an image. It's seems to work perfectly sometimes and sometimes it moves a little bit after zooming. I just can't figure out why..

Can anyone help me out why this happens

```css
    header {
            width: 65.277777777777778%;
            max-width: 1400px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: auto;
            margin-bottom: 6%;
        }
        
        .container {
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden;
            /* height: 200px;
            width: 200px; */
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .container img {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
            -webkit-transition: transform;
            transition: transform;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
            transition-duration: 1s;
            display: flex;
        }
        
        .container:hover img {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
            transform: scale(1.5);
            -webkit-transition: transform;
            transition: transform;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
            transition-duration: 1s;
        }
```

```html
<header>

        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/08/11/08/43/potatoes-1585060__340.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>

    </header>
```

Comment: works fine in chrome 58 on windows 8.1

Comment: sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.. (refresh)

Comment: just refreshed it five times, worked every time.

Comment: It would be nice if you try the codes in a other code editor than the from stack overflow :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try and see if it's more consistent for you. It works well for me, and I haven't noticed any issues in the months it's been implemented:

```
.container img {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.container img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
     -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
       -o-transform: scale(1.5);
          transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

See if this does the trick, if it's something you're interested in. Either way, let me know!